# Apache2 (debian) 403 forbidden page

Tags: apache, debian, http-status-code-403

When uploading a Laravel site to our Apache server, I had to change a few permissions to actually be able to view the site. It worked for a while but when working on the database, I messed up. I changed the owner and group of the Laravel app in the www folder instead of the (made by us) app folder (where the whole Laravel app is located).

When trying to access the site now, I keep getting a 403 Forbidden error. I created a new virtual host (and disabled the old Laravel host) to try what it would do but when trying to access to basic phpinfo page, I keep getting the 403. When using 'curl [ip]' through SSH, also a 403. I have no idea what to do. I checked quite a lot of sites but no solution worked for me. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Show the result of `ls -la` on your project root inside the server. Also, post your virtual host file. Are you using public/ as your http root?

Comment: This is my result of the ls -la: https://pastebin.com/eq2PAUjK

Comment: And this is my virtual host file: https://pastebin.com/jp5qJpEs

Comment: ^ Please add these snippets to your question, and then delete them from comments. A code formatting tool is available. Thanks!